# Evaluating $P= \dfrac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\dfrac{b^2}{2b^2+ca}+\dfrac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We are given that,
$$a+b+c=0$$
Then, what is the value of:
$$P= \dfrac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\dfrac{b^2}{2b^2+ca}+\dfrac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}$$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810606/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1741901/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/765440/42969.

Answer (score 1):

Use:$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc-a(a+b+c)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(b-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}=\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}=1.$$